# Python: how is it possible to convert a symbolic expression into a function so that it can be numerically integrated?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy, numerical-methods

I've been working with symbolic expressions in Python, and have arrived at one which I am wanting to integrate over a definite interval. The expression contains `pi`.

The trouble is that I have not been able to figure out how to convert this expression to a function which can be input as an argument to `scipy.integrate.quad`. The relevant parts of my code are as follows:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

# this defines the symbols that
# we will be using in our computations:
x, y, g, y1, a0, a1, a2 = symbols('x y g y1 a0 a1 a2')

# this defines what a0 and a1,
# and what y and y' are:

a0 = 2
a1 = -((2/pi)+(pi*a2))

y = a0+a1*x+a2*x**2
y1 = y.diff(x)   

# this defines the integrand that
# here represents the Lagrangian:

L=sqrt((1+y1**2)/(2*g*y))

# this differentiates the above with
# respect to a2, to define the integrand:

difL = L.diff(a2)
```

It is `difL` which I am wanting to integrate. I have tried defining it as a function in the following way:

```
def integrand(a2):
    return difL

f = lambdify(x, integrand(a2))
```

to no avail. So my question is: how can I convert `difL` into a function which can then be integrated using `scipy.integrate.quad`?

And, as a disclaimer, I am new to Python, so if I've been employing terms incorrectly, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need scipy, sympy is perfectly capable of numerical integration. Now, you have a lot of variables you are not defining (e.g. `g`) so I'll construct an easier example, and let you adapt to your question.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, a

# x is variable, a is parameter
y = x**2 + a

# integrate over x from 0 to 1; then evaluate with the value of the parameter
integrate(y, (x, 0, 1)).evalf(subs={a: -4})
```

Comment: thank-you for your response. The trouble with this method is that the integral must be computed symbolically prior to substitutions of numeric values being made (I think). This takes up a lot of computation time. What I'm wanting to do is numerically integrate so as to save time... which I should have made clear. (My integrand is incredibly complex, and there may not even exist an analytic antiderivative to it.)

Comment: No, you get symbolic simplification, but not evaluation. There’s a difference between `integrate(y, x)` (symbolic integration) vs `integrate(y, (x, x1, x2))` (numeric integration). And anyway, profile it :) At lunch now but I think you can get a function using `lambdify(difL.evalf(subs={a2:..., g:...})), i think, which you can give to scipy.

Comment: Back from lunch. Scratch that lambdify, there's something that errors out (even when I don't mess up the argument structure - should've been `lambdify(x, difL...)`). This works: `def f(xx): return difL.evalf(subs={a2:4, g:3, x:xx})`.

Comment: I ended up (and this seems to be working) defining a function `f = lambdify((x, a0, a1, a2, g), difL, 'numpy')`, and integrating that function using `scipy.integrate.quad`. I'm going to try your method now and see if it works better.

Comment: I guess you might be right; sympy's integrate takes ungodly time (I didn't have patience to wait it out).